Employer asking to open a business bank account. Is this job a scam or legit?
I was recently contacted by an employer that wanted to hire me as a Customer Service Officer. They have three ways to pay you: direct deposit, wire transfer, and cash transfer. I did the training with them and before I even started. They want me to be an online manager for the company as they want to open up an office in my state. The only difference would be to open up a business account. They don't allow personal accounts. I have been wary after hearing all this.
Could this be a scam? The supervisor told me they do W-2s at the end of the year and I don't have to worry about anything dealing with taxes they will take care of it.

What do you mean "open a business account"? Do they want you to be involved in opening up a bank account? This is definitely a scam. No legitimate company will involve a new hire in opening up a bank account.

If you have to ask "is it a scam", it probably is one.

Step back and look at that for a moment: they're offering you a job as an "officer" and styling you a "manager" despite knowing next to nothing about you. Does that sound pukka?

@MarkMorganLloyd: thank you. Today, I learned a new word.

While you are probably "weary" (tired), you likely meant that you have been "wary" (suspicious) after hearing all this. And well you should, it smells fishy all right.

@Grade'Eh'Bacon some banks do ask new hires to open an account. Usually, the employee benefits package are so big (no tariffs, unlimited withdrawals, etc etc) it justifies opening a new account anyway. It's not forced, though. But since you used involve, here you go.

Is the business account the account they're going to send your salary to, or an account they want you to open for the office's finances? The latter would normally be handled by the company's accounting department, not delegated to the manager of an office.

@MindwinRememberMonica To be clear - I mean no new employee is going to open an account for the company. Even if you got hired into the treasury department of a company, you wouldn't open an account for them before you had been onboarded and brought onto their banking platforms.

clarification received and agreed upon. Previous instructions unclear. Keep doing a good job.

When they say that you don't have to worry about anything dealing with taxes, do they mean that you don't have to worry about the tax withholding? That's normal for all W-2 jobs, so it's sort of weird for them to point it out. But I'm not sure what else they could mean, since you are always responsible for ensuring that your taxes are paid correctly each year.

"I was recently contacted by an employer...": unless you are a superstar in your chosen field, with potential employers fighting each other for the chance to plead with you to work for them, it sounds suspicious for them to contact you. I have received a few unsolicited offers of employment, during a 40 year career, but they have always been from someone who knew me. Have you checked their website? Does it look kosher?

One other suggestion: take their original email, and copy the offer into Google and search. Then add the word "scam" and search again. If this is a scam, which seems to be the consensus here, you are unlikely to be the first person the receive the "offer".
Alternatively, you may decide that you don't need to do a detailed analysis: if it smells bad, avoid it.

@SimonCrase Maybe it was actually a recruiter, not the bank itself, who made the initial contact. That's normal.


They want me to be an online manager for the company as they want to open up an office in my state

Do you know what that means? Renting an office, hiring employees, dealing with local business licensing, contracting vendors for janitorial services, office supplies, IT, etc... Have you done that before? If not - why do you think you're the right person for this?

The supervisor told me they do W-2s at the end of the year and I don't have to worry about anything dealing with taxes they will take care of it.

Given that you mentioned State and W2, I'm assuming you're in the US. In the US your taxes are your responsibility and noone else can take care of it.


They don't allow personal accounts. I have been weary after hearing all this. Could this be a scam?

Most likely. If you're an employee - then why do they care about your personal bank account?
They're offering you a fancy position that you're unlikely to actually be qualified for, asking you to create a bank account for them, and telling you to not report it in taxes. Is it a scam? Yes, most likely.

What do you mean with "why do they care about your personal bank account?"? You have to give your personal account details, so they pay you salary. Under details, I don't means password or anything similar ;)

@BЈовић he meant "why would they need you to have a business bank account rather than a personal one"

Great answer ! I always take a great care when somebody says "you only have to". Especially when these matters are related to personal finances. And in this specific case if OP is not planning to become a fully functional business legal unit, then this is a no-go.

@BЈовић In many US states, an employer cannot require that employees use direct deposit (therefore there'd be no reason for them to need know your account number, etc.)

I agree the situation is odd and probably not a normal job offer, but I have no idea what the scam could possibly be. Does any one have an idea of what the real plans of the "employer" may be?

@Amelian money laundering through the "business" account, probably.

@Amelian - whilst it's fine to be curious, it's important to remember that you don't have to know how a scam works in order to be the victim of a scam. "you" are a comparative amateur, these people run scams 24/7.

Absolutely everyone who asks you to open a special account somewhere is scamming you. There is no possible scenario in which someone needs you to open an account for their purposes.
If they were legitimate, they'd have ways to open their own account. Yes, even if they're out-of-state. Even if they were on the other side of the planet, a legitimate company will always be able to do their own banking, and any intermediates they might need would be lawyers or notaries.
Most likely scenario (but this is guesswork): They'll launder money through that account, and when eventually the whole operation goes belly up, their hands are clean and you're in a shitload of trouble.

Is this really true in the general international case?  I think you often need to be a legal resident of a country to open a bank account in it.  Thus, a company might well need an agent in order to incorporate and/or open a bank account--and that is a business in some countries. These rules were imposed to prevent money-laundering.  Of course, there is no reason this is required within a country, and if you are not an expert in the rules and laws, then...you are going to be left holding the bag.

@SethRobertson: If they need an agent to open an account, it will be a professional, not J. Random Non-Financial-Expert. If you have to ask here. It's a scam. If you can't explain why they are doing business with you rather than experts, it's a scam.

@SethRobertson There are people who's whole business model is to serve as agents for others. They're usually well-established, with legal counsel, and can properly vet their customers without asking questions on a random internet Q&A site.

In my experience, the moment somebody says "You don't need to worry about it", my spider sense starts tingling. The next question I ask is "Why not?".  Another good question to ask is "Tell me about my job description in more detail?".  Tell us what your training consisted of?  Training is expensive: if somebody starts training you before you get the job offer, that's another red flag.  Are they assuming you are so desperate (or stupid) that you will take any job?
Somebody else in this thread mentioned that if you have to ask, "Is this a scam?", then it probably is.
You were wise to bring up your question in this forum.  Unless you have signed a non-disclosure agreement, I recommend you post the name of the company and their contact information.  That way, if somebody looks for them using google, bing, or duckduckgo, then that person will find the story and themselves be wary.

No, don't post names. Defamation suits are expensive even when frivolous.

@littleadv it's impossible to defame someone by stating demonstrably true facts. As long as OP has a written record of all of this (@OP you do have a written record, right?) there's trivially nothing to sue over. A real company will know this and won't waste their time. A scam company obviously isn't going to sue you.

"A real company... won't waste their time." Lots of legitimate companies are run by stupid, malevolent, and/or highly emotional people. Frivolous lawsuits are filed by real companies quite often in the US.

@Brondahl anyone can sue you for anything, and just proving to the court that you didn't lie is going to be expensive. It is not at all a given that you'd be able to, and even if you do - that attorney fees are going to be awarded.

I have posted scam airlines on the travel site (while they were still openly scamming).   Their name and url is still up on the site, and yes they are still scamming.   Nothing wrong with posting scams as long as we stick to facts.

@Brondahl It is possible that the scammer has used the name, and copied the details, of A Real Company (ARC Inc). So that OP could be led to believe that she is actually working for ARC when she is actually involved with a bunch of sleazebags off-shore.

"it is impossible to defame someone by stating demonstrably true facts" Maybe so. But they could still sue you, and then you would have to prove to the court's satisfaction that what you said is, in fact, true. Courts are not magic. Just because you are in the right doesn't mean you automatically win without having to even hire a lawyer. It would be nice if true, but it's not.

An interesting observation: if we're now at the point where @littleadv's advice is received wisdom -- ie "don't post some details of a dubious job offer and have other people weigh in on it being a scam" -- the chilling effect is complete ._. While frivolous lawsuits might be expensive to defend, hypothetical lawsuits are absurdly cheap to 'file'...

@bertieb welcome to the US, I guess? Your speech is free as long as you can afford it.

@littleadv I kinda thought the US had some semblance of anti-SLAPP protections. Even still, you'd think someone asking "FooCorp have asked me to set up a business bank account, is this normal...?" would be in the clear, but I'm all to familiar with the "better safe than sorry" mindset

@bertieb even with anti-SLAPP protections, you'll need to retain an attorney, pay for a bunch of hours of their work, and hope they'd be able to convince the judge that the suit is meritless. And after that, the offended party may still come after you, e.g.: the story of Peter Thiel and Gawker.

@littleadv I'm not sure the Gawker lawsuit is relevant here, but just in case I will continue my policy of not publishing sex tapes of wrestlers and not outing billionaires...

Jokes aside, this is definitely getting into the long grass and way OT. That said, I think being careful about what you say on the internet is reasonable; but possibly there are cases where we are too cautious and do others a disservice by not presenting facts so others can learn from them. It can be a tough call though. Thankfully, Google helpfully suggests what others are searching for in its autocomplete, "CompanyName scam" being offered is usually not a great sign :)

Telling you that you:

don't have to worry about anything dealing with taxes they will take care of it.

should be a big reason to get away from that job. Head for the door and do not look back.
